# Unable to open PowerPoint presentation in edit mode powerpoint iPad from iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, powerpoint

I am building an iPad application which contains powerpoint presentations. when a user selects a presentation from app, it will opens in PowerPoint iPad Application. 
I tried using UIDocumentInteractionController to open  the  presentation which is stored in the document directory of my application, But it is opening in read only mode . Is it possible to open the presentation in edit mode?

I used the below Swift code to achieve the functionality  and it always opening in read only mode.

```
let newUrlStr = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCE54337-6614-4872-AB7F-945073E7F674/File%20Provider%20Storage/Presentation3.pptx"

let  newDocUrl = URL(string: newUrlStr)

documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: newDocUrl)

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

documentController!.presentOpenInMenu(from: frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it possible to open ppt files in swift???